# What do the below terms represent in the watchlist in Keat Pro X by Kotak Mahindra Securities?

Tags: stocks, online-tools, nse-india

What do the below terms represent in a watchlist created by a user in Keat Pro X by Kotak Mahindra Securities?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only answer some of them, and not being specifically familiar with that trading screen there's some educated guesswork here.

But a fair number of these are common enough terms.

- **Bid Prc** The current best bid price available from traders looking to buy the security. This would be the price you'd get if you sold your shares.
- **Bid Qty** How many shares they're looking to at that price.
- **Ask Prc** The current best asking price available from traders looking to sell the security. This is the price you'd pay to buy shares on the market.
- **Ask Qty** How many shares are available at that price.
- **Open** is the opening price to purchase shares when trading began that day.
- **High Prc, Low Prc** The highest and lowest prices, respectively, seen during that trading day.
- **Close** would probably be the last days closing price.
- **The arrows** Whether the price has moved down or up (generally in relation to the last days closing price)